# How to convert a string into a constant tuple in Python

Tags: python, string, tuples

Say I have a select box with some values such as 'RED', 'BLUE' and 'GREEN' and I want to use those strings as references to constants called the same thing, but containing tuples, as so:

```
RED = ('x234114','z8765667')
```

The code I am looking for would look something like this in my mind's eye :)

```
globals_lookup('RED')
```

This could be an obvious one, but it's not coming to me.

Comment: There is a [globals()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) function that returns a dictionary of the current global namespace... is this what you want?

Comment: Could you not just store the constants in a dictionary at global anyway?

Comment: I'm guessing since my comment and the first two answers all answered different questions you need to clarify what you want.

Comment: Thanks all. Yes, it was much simpler than I thought in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have defined the variable with the tuple you can access it by using locals.

```
>>> RED = ('x234114','z8765667')
>>> locals()["RED"]
('x234114', 'z8765667')
```

But the right way to do it would be using a dictionary

```
>>> select_data = {"RED" :('x234114','z8765667'),"BLUE":('x934587','z943657')}
>>> select_data["RED"]

('x234114','z8765667')
```

Answer (score 2):

Using eval:

```
RED = ('x234114','z8765667')
def globals_lookup(ident):
    return eval(ident)    
t=globals_lookup('RED')
```

But a better way would be using a hash table:

```
colors={'RED':('x234114','z8765667')}
t=colors['RED']
```

Comment: No need for `eval()`, just `return globals()[ident]`

Answer (score 1):

Use a Python dictionary:

```
lookup = {
    'RED' : ('x234114','z8765667')
}
```

usage:

```
color = "RED"
tup = lookup[color]
assert tup == ('x234114','z8765667')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RED = ('x234114','z8765667')
color_table = {'RED': RED, 'GREEN': GREEN, 'BLUE': BLUE}

def globals_lookup(color):
    return color_table[color]
```